# If $h(x) = f(x)-g(x)$ and $h(-1) = 0$ and $h(-2) = 2\;,$ Then $h(4)=$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If $f(x) = a_{1}x^2+b_{1}x+c_{1}$ and $g(x) = a_{2}x^2+b_{2}x+c_{2}$ and $h(x) = f(x)-g(x)$
>
> and $h(-1) = 0$ and $h(-2) = 2\;,$ Then $h(4)=\;,$ Where $a_{1},a_{2}\neq 0$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Here $h(x)$ is a difference of two quadratic polynomial

So $h(x)= = (a_{1}-a_{2})x^2+(b_{1}-b_{2})x+(c_{1}-c_{2}) = ax^2+bx+c$

And given $h(-1) = 0\;$ and $h(-2) = 2$

So $h(x)= a(x+1)(x-\beta),$ Put $\beta = -2$

$\displaystyle h(-2) = 2= A(\beta+1)\Rightarrow A=\frac{2}{\beta+1}$

So $$h(4) = 4A\cdot 5 \cdot (4-\beta) = 40\frac{4-\beta}{\beta+1}$$

Now how can i calculate $h(4)\;,$ Help required, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Either I am missing something, or you must be missing something; this information does not uniquely define $h(4)$. First of all, $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$, even with $a_1,a_2\neq 0$, does not restrict $h(x)$; you can get any $a=a_1-a_2$ as a difference of two non-zero numbers.

Given $h(x)=ax^2+bx+c; h(-1)=0;h(-2)=2$, we substitue -1 and -2 and write, $$a-b+c=0\\ 4a-2b+c=2 $$ Solving the matrix equation gives, $$\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\0\end{bmatrix} + k \cdot \begin{bmatrix}1\\3\\2\end{bmatrix} ,$$ or, $$a=1+k; b=1+3k; c=2k ,$$ where k is any real coefficient (you can substitute and check for x=-1 and x=-2).
Then, x=4 gives you $h(4)=20+30k$, which is dependent on free variable k.

Answer (score 1):

There is no unique solution. To obtain a parameterized one, let $a=a_1-a_2, b=b_1-b_2, c_1-c_2$ so that $h(x)=a x^2 + b x +c$. Then the $h(-1) = 0$ and $h(-2) = 2\;$ conditions give:

$$
\begin{cases}
a-b+c=0 \\ 4a - 2b + c = 2
\end{cases}
$$

and by direct subtraction:

$$3a -b = 2$$

so:

$$
\begin{cases}
b = 3 a - 2 \\
c = 2 a -2
\end{cases}
$$

Then:

$$
h(4) \;\;=\;\; 16 a + 4 b + c \;\;=\;\; 30 a - 10 \;\;=\;\; 30(a_1 - a_2) - 10
$$